# DevExpress VerticalGrid Row properties

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, repositorylookupedit

I use `DevExpress 22`. I add an `EditorRow` to the `VerticalGrid`. In `EditorRow` properties for `RowEdit` selected `LookUpEdit` from `In-place Editor repository`. `LookUpEdit` contains a list from the database with color names. when I select a color name from the list, the `EditorRow` is painted in that color. but, when I select a color from the list, it is not applied immediately, only when I remove the focus from the `EditorRow`.
I use `EditValueChanged` to handle selecting value from a list:

```
private void Ilue_zprstatus_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LookUpEdit ilue = sender as LookUpEdit;
    
    if (ilue.EditValue.ToString() == "Green")
    {                                
        zpr_status.AppearanceCell.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0x99, 0xFF, 0x99);               
    }              
    if (ilue.EditValue.ToString() == "Yellow")
    {               
        zpr_status.AppearanceCell.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x99);
    }
    if (ilue.EditValue.ToString() == "White")
    {
        zpr_status.AppearanceCell.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);          
    }            
}
```

the function works, but the color does not change immediately.
Questions:

1. How to refresh the `EditorRow` state immediately after selecting a value from the list?
2. How to get in `EditorRow` the value of `DisplayMember` from `LookUpEdit` instead of `ValueMember`?

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the lookup repository item's `EditValueChanged` event. See the following code sample:

```
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    vGridControl1.DataSource = ColorRecord.Init();
    vGridControl1.ForceInitialize();
    RepositoryItemLookUpEdit lookupColor = new RepositoryItemLookUpEdit();            
    lookupColor.ValueMember = "Color"; // Type - Color
    lookupColor.DisplayMember = "ColorName"; // Type - String
    lookupColor.EditValueChanged += new EventHandler(loolupColor_EditValueChanged);
    vGridControl1.Rows["Color"].Properties.RowEdit = lookupColor; // Type - Color
}
// Fires once you selected a values from the dropdown list.
void loolupColor_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Gets the lookup's value.
    Color selectedColor = (Color)(sender as LookUpEdit).EditValue;
    // Gets the lookup's display text.
    string colorName = (sender as LookUpEdit).Text;
    // Posts the selected value to the vGrid's data source.
    vGridControl1.PostEditor();
}
```

Comment: can i get value `lookupColor.Text` without `sender`? for example, by pressing some button on the form and display the value of `DisplayMember` in `ShowMessage`?

Comment: 'vGridControl1.PostEditor()' has no effect.  the color of the field still changes only after removing the focus from this field